# The filter mechanism in Hibernate hbm file is not very flexible for dynamic predicates

Tags: java, hibernate, security, filter, orm

I am developing a Spring framework and hibernate application with a central database for an enterprise web application that has 
about 1000 users online daily.

You can assume that there is a billing application and anybody can do anything on his own account (e.g. increase the amount of his billing or
decrease the amount of his billing).

Any user has its own data which is secured to the specific user by a mechanism of filtering in hbm files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="true">
    <class name="org.myoffice.Inventory" table="Core_INVENTORY">
       <id name="id" column="Id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_INVENTORY</param>   
            </generator>
        </id>

        <many-to-one    name="bill"             column="bill_ID"        entity-name="org.myoffice.Bill" not-null="true" unique-key="unq_StrHouse_Smp_Pn_Exp"/>
        <property       name="expireDate"       column="expire_Date"    type="date" unique-key="unq_StrHouse_Smp_Pn_Exp"/>   
        <many-to-one    name="user"             column="user_id"        entity-name="org.myoffice.User" not-null="true"  update="false" />

        <many-to-one    name="createdBy"        column="CreatedBy"      entity-name="org.myoffice.User" not-null="true"  update="false" />
        <many-to-one    name="updatedBy"        column="UpdatedBy"      entity-name="org.myoffice.User" not-null="true"  />
        <property       name="createdDate"      column="CreatedDate"    type="date"         not-null="true" update="false" />
        <property       name="updatedDate"      column="UpdatedDate"    type="date"         not-null="true"/>   
        <property       name="ip"               column="IP"             type="string"       not-null="true"/>


        <filter name="powerAuthorize" condition="[SQL QUERTY IS HERE FOR RESTRICTION ANY USER TO OWN DATA]"/>           
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

NOTE: The end of ([SQL QUERTY IS HERE FOR RESTRICTION ANY USER TO OWN DATA]) in above hbm is finished with a WHERE CLAUSE has userId parameter 
for restricting a user to his own data and this userId is added the below method of generic repository.

And I add the powerAuthorize of hbm in my generic repository like this:

```
public void applyDefaultAuthorizeFilter(Session session) {
         Filter filter = session.enableFilter("powerAuthorize");
         filter.setParameter("userId", SecurityUtility.getAuthenticatedUser().getId());
      }
```

This filter always add to end of any query for filtering data.

Everything had been working fine until the consumer of my application brought up a new demand which is not compatible with this current design. The consumer now wants to increase the billing of another user.

If I skip the filter hbm, any user will see the information of another user and if i dont skip the filter, I can't implement this new request.

Is there other mechanism, pattern or anything else I could use instead?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Filter` is useful when the condition does not change, but just the bind parameter value can vary.

What you need here is to filter the WHERE clause predicate. Therefore, you need to move the filtering logic in your data access layer.

1. You write DAO methods to filter the Inventory based on user rights.
2. You remove the `@Filter` since the DAO methods will do that instead.

This design is much more flexible on the long term too.

Comment: As i undrestand from your posting is that i write some methods in the repository  instead of filtering in hbm file and call any of that depending on the situation for appending to end of any query.Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use several filters and enable/disable them on demand. E.g. activate your "powerAuthorize" filter for all requests and just enable another filter "comprehensiveAuthorize" for your new requirement and disable "powerAuthorize" temporary.

Comment: I have done my problem with your solution but there is a concern in that if this filter is used in total or half of application,i must change all of them and if a new demand that is for developing is requested in future on this object[org.myoffice.Inventory], this disable/enable must be care about

Comment: Is there a central solution in that changing it,effect to all?

Comment: Since the filters must be enabled for each hibernate session there could be a central place in your code that could handle the filters. I'm not that familiar with Spring, but is there any code that acquires the hibernate session that could be manipulated/overriden? Would be a good place for central filter handling...